# Shop module is not properly working with Magnolia CMS 5.4

Tags: magnolia

I have tried Shop Module 2.3-SNAPSHOT with Magnolia CMS 5.4, I have noticed UI components are not same used in Shop module and Magnolia CMS 5.4. Once I installed shop module  /travel page does not work.  Does anyone knows a workaround or better version of Shop module work smoothly with Magnnolia CMS 5.4 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2.3 version has quite few changes (hence the new major version number) and afaik demo have not been updated yet. So either you use it w/o demo (since it's snapshot no guarantee that nothing else is broken) or you stick to version 2.2 that is released and there's number of installations with that version and Magnolia 5.4.x.

Alternatively, you figure out what is broken in demo and provide patches for the issue. This is community driven module after all.

HTH,
Jan

Comment: Thanks Jan, I will try with version 2.2 with demo first, I would really like to contribute, TBH still early days for me. Trying to understand things :)